# How don't allow iOS to start application when specific type of push notification arrives?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want PHP server send to my iOS application two types of push notifications:

1. New income message. For this push I  want iOS start my application if it was suspended, show badge, play sound, etc.
2. New friend request. I don't want this push to start my application and I only want to handle if the app is in the foreground.

   How can I achieve this? How can I handle different push notifications differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will work, but you should try for your 2nd scenario to send a notification that contains only custom properties. In this case there will be no alert to display, sound to play nor badge to update, so I think this notification will only reach your app if it's already running.

For the 1st scenario, send a notification with pre-defined properties (alert, sound, badge).

Answer (score 0):

Application-side handling for remote notifications should start with the method in the application delegate protocol application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:.

However, in order to avoid the application launching in the first place, you need to make sure the PHP server crafted notification doesn't offer the option to launch the application.

See the documentation on the Apple Push Notification Service here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9

In particular, you want to focus on the content of the aps dictionary as documented in The Notification Payload section. The aps dictionary received can badge your application's icon without opening the app at all.